Mindmap: set branch length
I'm building a Mindmap, and want to display the relationship between two concepts in it's own bubble, i.e. a third level concept.  Unfortunately, the third level (explanation) eclipses the main concept.  I want it to be more centered between the main concept and the subconcept.
The code :
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pgfdeclarelayer{main}
\pgfsetlayers{main}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,concept color=red!50]
    \node [concept] {Main \\Concept}
        child[concept color=orange, grow=135] {node[concept] (B1){Subconcept}
            [clockwise from=-45]
            child { node[concept] {Relation }  }  
        }
        child[concept  color=green, grow=45] {node[concept] (B2) {Subconcept}
            [clockwise from=225]
            child { node[concept] {Relation }  }  
        }
        child[concept  color=blue, grow=315, color=white] {node[concept] (c1) {Subconcept}
            [clockwise from=135]
            child { node[concept] {Relation}  } 
        } ;

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
        \draw [concept connection] (B1) edge (B2);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

yields:

which looks quite awkward.
The Tikz pgf manual version 1.18 doesn't mention being able to adjust the tenticle length.  A search yields the following answer, but it deals with tree length:
Length of branches in forest (LaTex)

Are you maybe looking for \begin{tikzpicture}[   mindmap,   concept color=red!50,   level 1/.append style={level distance=7cm}, ]? https://i.sstatic.net/bZcuq4LU.png

1.18? PGF/TikZ is currently on version 3.1.10.
